# cross platform syncing solution with offline and relationship support

Tags: android, ios, core-data, dropbox, synchronization

I am relatively new to app development and core data, so take it easy on me. I have been working on an app (currently for iOS, android in the future too) which stores the user's data locally using core data.
The data has relationships across entities. User can create, update, delete data.

Now I need to integrate some kind of syncing solution. My requirements are:

1. Data should be accessible offline (right now I am testing queue operations for that)
2. Data should sync to cloud storage when network is available (on iOS I have tested out reachability for this)
3. Cloud storage needs to be integrateble to both my current iOS and future android version.
4. Relationships (or some other way of linking parent-child, i talk about it later) need to be maintained.
5. Core data on ios should be used, not third party replacement.

I have messed around with many solutions so far:

1. I setup my own rethinkdb database on a server and used PHP and REST to get things going. This was very messy.
2. I tested parse.com and afnetworking http requests (instead of parse's library)  - this was better, but i couldn't seem to be able to manage the relationships from core data. And my syncing algorithm is complicated (it works but I am not sure if there are holes in it when it may fail)
3. I tested dropbox datastore api. I have only tested the iOS sample app they provide, seemed pretty good (still need to understand the workings).

**My questions are:**

1. If I were to use dropbox datastore api, how does it work with android? of course core data is not available there, so how does that work (sorry I don't have android dev experience yet)? ALso how does it handle relationships between entities?
2. If I go with Parse.com, do you think my this idea will work-
   Instead of using relationships, I can use identifiers? my relationships are all 1-to-many, so on the parent (1) I can have an id A. On all the children I can point their parentid to A. Also since my children can have grandchildren too, on each of the children I can have another id which the grandchildren can point to. So on... does this make sense as a replacement of relationships? If yes, then what's the point of relationships in xcode?? other than having automatic cascade option maybe.
3. Are there any better solutions available for syncing cross platform?

I know my question may seem a bit asking for opinion, but I would like to see what everyone else has already tried. Past week of switching from one solution to another and designing the syncing algorithm has fried my brain.

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Dropbox and will address just that part of the question.)

The Dropbox Datastore API doesn't use core data and thus works exactly the same way on Android. Why is core data a requirement?

As to relationships, what you describe for Parse is exactly what I would suggest for use with the Datastore API. I believe you're right that the reason for modeling relationships in databases and in code is to get automatic cascading operations and enforcement of relationship invariants.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Core data is a requirement as i have already spent a month of work on this app. So I really don't want to change my architecture. Also core data and NSFetchRequestController seem to work really perfectly with my table views. So I need to keep it in place. How does dropbox handle the data then? I looked at the sample "toado" app and I noticed some nsfetchrequest and stuff in there, so I thought it used core data? no?

Comment: No, the Datastore API doesn't use core data. Under the hood, it stores the local cache of the data in its own sqlite database and uses an async op queue to communicate deltas to the server.

Comment: oh ok. I guess dropbox is not an option for me then :(

Comment: Well, if you're going to go cross-platform, core data won't be an option. So I expect you'll move away from it eventually anyway. When that happens, I hope you consider the Datastore API. :-)